# Why is method returning nothing?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I make a new user so lets say I have:

```
$user = new User(10);
```

According to my user.php class it should take that number and find the user with the id of 10 and store its data. So when I type:

```
$user->data();
```

I should get the first user with the id 10 data, but for some reason when I type `$user->data()` nothing happens.

Here is the class.

```
<?php

class User {
  private $_db,
          $_data,
          $_sessionName,
          $_cookieName,
          $_isLoggedIn;

  public function __construct($user = null){
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

    $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
    $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');


    if(!$user){
      if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
        $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

          if($this->find($user)) {
            $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
          } else {
              // process logout
          }
        } else {
        $this->find($user);
      }
    }
  }

  public function update($fields = array(), $chosenfield = 'id', $id= null) {

    if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
      $id = $this->data()->id;
    }

    if(!$this->_db->update('users', $chosenfield, $id, $fields)) {
      throw new Exception('There was a problem updating.');
    }
  }

  public function create($table,$fields = array()){
    if(!$this->_db->insert($table, $fields)){
      throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account.');
    }
  }


  public function find($user = null) {
    if($user){
      $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
      $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));
      if($data->count()) {
        $this->_data = $data->first();
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }


  public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = false) {
    if(!$username && !$password && $this->exists() === 'true') {
      Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
      } else {
      $user = $this->find($username);
      if($user){
        if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
          Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

          if($remember){
            $hash = Hash::unique();
            $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

            if(!$hashCheck->count()) {
              $this->_db->insert('users_session',array(
                'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                'hash' => $hash
              ));
            } else {
              $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
            }

            Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
          }
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }


  public function hasPermission($key) {
    $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));

    if($group->count()) {
      $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

      if($permissions[$key] == true){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
   }

  public function exists() {
    return (!empty($this->_data)) ? true : false;
  }


  public function data(){
    return $this->_data;
  }


  public function isLoggedIn(){
    return $this->_isLoggedIn;
  }


  public function logout(){

    $this->_db->delete('users_session', array('user_id' ,'=' , $this->data()->id));

    Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
    Cookie::delete($this->_cookieName);
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(!$user){` Passing `10` to `__construct` means that `$user` is **TRUE**.

Comment: yes but shouldn't it then go through $this->find($user);

Comment: I have added alot of testing to see whats working and whats not working in this class. If you go to find() method everything in that method is working so field is returning id, data is getting that user with the id of 10 and $this->_data = $data->first() is even giving me the first user with id of 10, I just cant figure out why my data method isnt returning that value

Comment: No it shouldn't, because `find($user)` is in `if`-clause. Please, check your logics once again.

Comment: isnt the if($this->find($user)) mean that it will find it ?

Comment: If i echo out the variables in find  method they work as of now. like i said before so it is being passed through that method one way or another

Comment: What I'm saying is it would pass through true the first if and then see if session exists which would be false unless I logged in with that user, which I have not so it then would go to the else $this->find($user);

Comment: @NewbieCoder No, it will never enter the first if `if(!user)` since `!10 == false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misread the code before, the problem is exactly what m_ulder said in his comment.

When you say this:

```
new User(10);
```

In the constructor, this statement is false

```
if (!$user)
```

and the code inside it never executes, which is **all** the code inside the function.

That is because `$user` is TRUE when $user is 10 -- or any other value.

Comment: Well I am doing a tutorial from codecourse and I'm pretty sure that is how he does it. Because if a session does not exist we want to find the user still you know? Where exactly should I move it if its wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code, my answer is wrong.  Give me a moment to take another look!

Comment: I think you are right that I should start with something more simple. But , I think I get what you are saying . So if the user does exists I want to find that user so I need to put the else at the end of the if(!user). Is that correct?

Comment: I've rewritten my answer after misreading, the short version is that m_ulder was completely correct in his comment to you, and I misread the code before writing my last answer.

Comment: Yes I put the else in the wrong place basically! Thank you so much for taking the time to help, not a lot of people do now days.!

Comment: Is there a way you could help me with finding out why my cookie wont work or wont log the user in when they close the browser and reopen it?

Comment: Please make sure you read the new answer -- simply changing where the else is, is not going to fix your issue entirely I don't think, but I have not looked it over closely.  The cookie issue may be related, open another question! :)

Comment: Cookie issued was fixed also!! Thanks so much!